# Having hard time with selecting appropriate variable names

Tags: language-agnostic, naming-conventions, conventions

I'm mostly developing in JS, but since React and his friends entered my life I feel like I'm writing much more variable names, more than I used to do and I'm having troubles with naming them.

Usually trying to pick something that I can remember and someone else can remember too, also trying to be logical and not annoyingly long.

So for instance in a messaging app, `user` might represent `logged in user`, `recipient user`, or `user API`.

What I do is usually `user` refers to any other user in the system.
`me` refers to the logged-in user. API depends...

What do you do? Is it something that should be camelcase with long variable names?

userLoggedIn, userRecepient, userAPI etc? Is there a commonly used pattern or a source (book, community, etc.) that I can look up to?

Answer (score 1):

My strategy is to first think about what the variable stands for in the most general sense. In your example it's a *user*. Then I prefix the noun with attributes which makes it sufficiently precise. In your example it would be *loggedInUser* or *currentUser*, and *recipientUser*. I would not recommend the name *userLoggedIn*  in this context because it sounds like a truth value (boolean variable). For boolean variables I start by thinking of an adjective and add nouns in front of it.

Comment: I see, I was trying to use suffixes instead of prefixes so feels like I'm grouping related stuff but you are right, sounds like a truth value.

Answer (score 0):

The naming variable is one of the hardest problem in computer science, so it's not surprised that you feel difficult when naming variable.

`Is there a commonly used pattern or a source (book, community, etc.) that I can look up to?` -> Unfortunately, there's nothing common structure to do it. It's up to your project and your experience.

As a 4-year experience as developer, I can share you some tips to do it:

1. `Don't make the name too abstract.` Let's image that you're new in the project, when you see the variable or function, you must understand what this function do.
2. `Always use the verb as the first in the function`
3. `Use the "has/have" with noun and "is" with adjective`

*For example:*

```
 - "hasSavedRow", not "isSavedRow"
 - "isSelected", not "hasSelected"
```

4. `Apply the PascalCase for interface, namespace, component, type.`
5. `Apply the CamelCase for function, callback, variable`